# different behavior in gnu preprocessor and clang preprocessor

Tags: fortran, preprocessor, c-preprocessor

I have a simple FORTRAN code

```
#define  DTYPE(a) a/**/_s
TYPE,EXTENDS(DTYPE(type1)) :: DTYPE(type2)
CLASS(DTYPE(type1)_), POINTER :: x => NULL()
CONTAINS
PROCEDURE :: comp => DTYPE(comp1)
END TYPE DTYPE(type2)
#undef DTYPE
```

Using GNU preprocessor I will get the correct behavior which I expect, while using CLANG preprocessor it will behave completely strange.

using cpp-4.9 (GNU)

```
cpp-4.9 -traditional-cpp -P test.f
```

:

```
TYPE,EXTENDS(type1_s) :: type2_s
CLASS(type1_s_), POINTER :: x => NULL()
CONTAINS
PROCEDURE :: comp => comp1_s
END TYPE type2_s
```

using cpp (CLANG)

```
cpp -traditional-cpp -P test.f
```

:

```
TYPE,EXTENDS(type1 _s) :: type2 _s
CLASS(type1 _s _), POINTER :: x => NULL()
CONTAINS
PROCEDURE :: comp => comp1 _s
END TYPE type2 _s
```

using cpp (CLANG) there is an extra space which will cause compiler error. Does anyone know what is the problem?

Comment: FWIW intel's `fpp` behaves the same as `clang` and adds a space.

Comment: why are you using traditional mode?

Comment: I have a huge library and I need the traditional mod for some parts, but you are right in this piece of code it is not necessary to use the traditional mode. With or without traditional mode does not change the problem. Is there anyway I can overcome this problem in using CLANG preprocessor?

Comment: @agentp cpp for gfortran always uses the traditional mode if not called separately from the compiler.

Comment: without traditional mode you can use concatenation, `a ## _s`. As Ive never used cpp with fortran I haven't a clue what other issues that creates though.

Comment: One problem without using -tranditional-cpp is that some tokens in C are not tokens in Fortran so you could get the wrong result.  This is why -tranditional-cpp is used.